# What is the best practice for linking AutoML API and Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, google-cloud-automl, automl

I'm looking for a tutorial to explain the connection between AutoML API and Flutter in detail. It can be a video, sample coding or a blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a couple of tutorial out there. Have you gone through those two already?

- https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/easily-build-image-classification-models-using-just-your-smartphone-walkthrough-guide-43bf211181b0
- https://medium.com/@epynic/using-automl-vision-in-your-next-flutter-app-3cc436312443